# Closure - different behavior on JS Fiddle & on simple HTML file

Tags: javascript, scope, closures, global-variables, jsfiddle

I am writing a simple example to demonstrate closure. When I am writing this on JS Fiddle I can see closure value passed properly in console. Same if I try make a HTML page and see in console. The closure passed cannot be seen. For both cases I am using Chrome. Why different behavior when code is the same and browser is the same? Where's the magic?

#### HTML

```
<script> 
var a = 10; 
var addTo = function(){
var b = 20;
return (a + b); 
}
console.dir(addTo);
</script>
```

#### jsFiddle

[image]

#### index.html

[image]

Comment: JSFiddle probably wraps the javascript in a IIFE, so you lose the Global scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you paste this code on JS Fiddle, the content of the `<script>` tag actually looks like that:

```
//<![CDATA[
window.onload=function(){
var a = 10; 
var addTo = function(){
var b = 20;
return (a + b); 
}
console.dir(addTo);
}//]]>
```

That creates another closure, and `a` belongs to that closure.

However, if you run this code in a simple HTML file, there's no closure, and `a` belongs to the global scope.